# Какая частица нужна: НЕ или НИ?

Tags: частица-не, выбор-варианта, ни

Я запутался...

*Как бы он мне **не** нравился как человек, и внешне и ментально... но он реально номер 1 сейчас.*

Какая частица здесь нужна? ***Ни*** явно не подходит, потому что с ней получается, что *он нравится*. Но и ***не*** выглядит как-то странно. Может, вообще всё предложение некорректно?

Comment: Если хотите использовать «не», замените «как бы» на «хоть»: _Хоть он мне и не нравился…»_

Comment: @Слава То есть «как бы» нельзя использовать? Это не мое предложение, если что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В предложении пропущена частица ***НИ:***

***Как бы он мне ни не** нравился как человек, и внешне и ментально... **но** он реально номер 1 сейчас.*

Это придаточное уступительное с союзом ***КАК БЫ НИ...НО***

Сравнить: ***Хотя** он мне не нравится, **но** он реально номер 1 сейчас.*

2. **Вывод**

Вариант с союзом ***КАК БЫ НИ*** нежелателен из за повтора частиц ***НИ*** и ***НЕ***. Такая запись выглядит стилистически **некорректной.**

Нужно использовать варианты с другой **грамматикой:** подчинительный союз ***ХОТЯ...НО*** или только  сочинительный союз ***НО.***

Answer (score 2):

Именно "вообще всё предложение некорректно". Зачем нам кагбэ? Оно с отрицанием несочитабельно.

Убираем условный зачин:

*Он мне не нравился как человек, и внешне и ментально... но он реально номер 1 сейчас.*